# Need to select only patients who have not specific codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have here an issue in this sql - it will give me the rows that are not these diagnosis codes. But a patient can have them as well.

I need patients who do not have these 3 codes
 V72.31', 'Z01.411', 'Z01.419'   at all.

```
SELECT  distinct "Vouchers"."Patient_ID" 
FROM   (("Ntier_70751"."PM"."Service_Diagnoses" "Service_Diagnoses" 
INNER JOIN "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Services" "Services" 
ON "Service_Diagnoses"."Service_ID"="Services"."Service_ID") 
INNER JOIN "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Diagnosis_Codes" "Diagnosis_Codes" 
ON "Service_Diagnoses"."Diagnosis_Code_ID"="Diagnosis_Codes"."Diagnosis_Code_ID") 
INNER JOIN "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Vouchers" "Vouchers" ON "Services"."Voucher_ID"="Vouchers"."Voucher_ID"
WHERE  "Diagnosis_Codes"."Diagnosis_Code" not in ('V72.31', 'Z01.411', 'Z01.419')
```

Comment: Use `where not exists`

Comment: I tried this WHERE  not exists "Diagnosis_Codes"."Diagnosis_Code" in ('V72.31', 'Z01.411', 'Z01.419') 
  but get error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'Diagnosis_Codes'.

Comment: what does your query outputs  ?

Comment: I just need the patient_Id, I will use in a crystal reports against the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired outcome is unclear.

This will show patients who have your "invalid" codes, so long as they have at least one code that is not in your exclusion list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    v.Patient_ID 
FROM
    Ntier_70751.PM.Service_Diagnoses sd

    INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Services s 
    ON sd.Service_ID = s.Service_ID

    INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Diagnosis_Codes dc 
    ON sd.Diagnosis_Code_ID = dc.Diagnosis_Code_ID 
    AND dc.Diagnosis_Code not in ('V72.31', 'Z01.411', 'Z01.419') 

    INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Vouchers v 
    ON s.Voucher_ID= v.Voucher_ID
```

And this one will exclude patients who have at least one of the "invalid" codes (regardless of what other "valid" codes they may have):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    v.Patient_ID
FROM
    Ntier_70751.PM.Vouchers v 
WHERE
    v.Patient_ID NOT IN

(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        v.Patient_ID 
    FROM
        Ntier_70751.PM.Service_Diagnoses sd

        INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Services s 
        ON sd.Service_ID = s.Service_ID

        INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Diagnosis_Codes dc 
        ON sd.Diagnosis_Code_ID = dc.Diagnosis_Code_ID 
        AND dc.Diagnosis_Code in ('V72.31', 'Z01.411', 'Z01.419') 

        INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Vouchers v 
        ON s.Voucher_ID= v.Voucher_ID
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you attempting to do this umpteen-way join?  I'm sure there's a far more efficient way to do things.  We need, however, a more precise description of what you're trying to achieve.

The problem is the scope to which the restricting WHERE clause is applied.  You are essentially saying

```
SELECT . . .  
FROM (THIS  
JOIN THAT  
JOIN (THEOTHERONE WHERE . . .))
```

when what you actually need is:

```
SELECT . . .  
FROM (THIS JOIN THAT JOIN THEOTHERONE)  
WHERE . . .
```

By constructing the multi-way join, you are picking up and tacking on other tuples that may contain those unwanted diagnosis codes.  Do your selection ("selection" means WHERE; SELECT is actually "projection" [poor choice of keywords from the creators of SQL) at the last possible moment.

Here's a suggestion.  Today, you want to reject records where the diagnosis codes match, say, A, B, or C; tomorrow you may want to ALSO reject records where the diagnosis codes match P or Q.  You should GENERALIZE this to make it TABLE-DRIVEN: create a second table

```
CREATE TABLE  REJECTION_CATEGORY( CATEG, DIAGN_CODE )  
PRIMARY KEY( CATEG, DIAGN_CODE )
```

and initialize it with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO REJECTION_CATEGORY VALUES( 1, 'V72.31 ),  
VALUE ( 1, 'Z01.411' ),  
VALUES( 1, 'Z01.419' )
```

then you can change your first query to:

```
SELECT . . .  
FROM (join-of-this-and-that)  
WHERE DIAGNOSIS_CODE NOT IN (  
    SELECT DIAGN_CODE  
    FROM REJECTION_CATEGORY  
    WHERE CATEG = 1)
```

and tomorrow's query, which rejects a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT set of diagnosis codes, just changes the last line but one to read **WHERE CATEG = 2**.

Comment: I see, interesting idea, Thanks.